# checkboxlist - how to populate it without setting selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox list as follows

```
                    CheckBoxList checkboxlist = new CheckBoxList();
                    checkboxlist.ID = controlID;
                    checkboxlist.Text = shortLabel;
                    checkboxlist.Width = width;
                    checkboxlist.RepeatColumns = columnnum;
                    checkboxlist.DataSource = furnitureItems;
                    checkboxlist.DataTextField = "ShowValue";
                    checkboxlist.DataValueField = "ShowValue";
                    checkboxlist.SelectedValue = //how can i set this to "nothing";
                    checkboxlist.DataBind();
```

when i set checkboxlist.selectedvalue = "";, I get an error that selected value must be specified. Is there a way around this?, I want all the checkboxes to show unchecked as the initial state. I would appreciate the help.

Please let me know if there is additional information required.

Comment: what happened if you omit that line - like not setting it?

Comment: @user710502: If you omit that line and you still get the error, then that error _probably_ isn't coming from that line.  Where do you actually get the error?  What other information does the error have?  A stack trace or something equally useful?  Can you supply more details?  For example, what is `furnitureItems`?  Why are the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` the same?

Comment: furnitureItems is a TList<furniture> , DataTextField and DataValueField are the same because the value is the same as the text specified in the text field. The error happens at this line checkboxlist.DataBind();

Comment: You should show us the actual stacktrace not your "translation". It's not mandatory to specify the `SelectedValue`. However, if you do it you need to specify a valid value. An empty string is invalid. I assume that this is a postback, isn't it?

Comment: I will provide a stack trace in a few. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not mandatory to specify the [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx). However, if you do it you need to specify a valid value. An empty string is invalid.

If you want to deselect the `CheckBoxList`, use the [`SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) property:

```
checkboxlist.SelectedIndex = -1:
```